# The "contrary" of an isomorphism

Tags: model-theory

Roughly, my question is: is there a standard name for functions which one might characterise as the "contrary" of an isomorphism?

Here is a more precise version of my question. Working model-theoretically, consider the following definition.

> **Definition.** Let $\mathscr{L}$ be a relational signature, and let $\mathcal{A}, \mathcal{B}$ be $\mathscr{L}$-structures. An *$\mathscr{L}$-anti-embedding* $\pi : A \longrightarrow B$ is any injection such that:
>
> $(a_1, \ldots, a_n) \in R^\mathcal{A}$ iff $(\pi(a_1), \ldots, \pi(a_n)) \notin R^\mathcal{B}$, for each $n$-place predicate $R \in \mathscr{L}$ and all $a_1, \ldots, a_n \in A$
>
> A bijective $\mathscr{L}$-anti-embedding is an *$\mathscr{L}$-anti-isomorphism*. An $\mathscr{L}$-anti-isomorphism from a structure to itself is an *$\mathscr{L}$-anti-automorphism*.

My question is: are there standard names for the kinds of functions I just defined? Indeed, are they discussed anywhere?

I have only encountered one such function "in the wild". I was reading Thomas Forster on Church-Oswald set theory; he called his $\{\in\}$-anti-automorphism an "antimorphism". (NB that, in the Church-Oswald setting, self-membered sets are perfectly ok.)

*Update*: Googling the phrase "anti-isomorphism" teaches me that, in group theory, an *anti-isomorphism* is standardly defined as a bijection $\pi : \mathcal{G} \longrightarrow \mathcal{H}$ such that $\pi(x \cdot^\mathcal{G} y) = \pi(y) \cdot^\mathcal{H} \pi(x)$. That's obviously a totally different idea. So I should use a different name! If there is no standard name, I welcome suggestions!

Comment: Hi Tim - welcome to MathOverflow! I would say in a "set setting", the contrary of an isomorphism is a constant map. Maybe there is some categorical or model theoretical setting in which we can say that a morphism is "constant".

Comment: @DominicvanderZypen How are constant functions contrary to isomorphisms in the sense specified by the OP?

Comment: @DominicvanderZypen - maybe my mention of set theory was helpful, as Church-Oswald set theory is quite unusual. In the context of set theories, an anti-isomorphism is a bijection $\pi$ such that $a \in^\mathcal{A} b$ iff $\pi(a) \notin^\mathcal{B} \pi(b)$. Trivially, there are no anti-isomorphisms between models of ZFC, since they'd need to send the empty set of one model to a universal set in the other. Here's an easy way to obtain anti-isormorphic models though: take an $\{\in\}$-structure $\mathcal{A} $, and define $\in^\mathcal{B}$ as $(A \times A) \setminus\mathord{\in^\mathcal{A}}$.

Comment: For semigroups an anti-isomorphism is a bijaction with $f(xy)=f(y)f(x)$. This is stndard. In the case of groups it is equivalent to isomorphism.

Comment: @MarkSapir: thanks. I mentioned this in an update, maybe I should make it more explicit (to avoid confusion). And certainly I should avoid using the name "anti-isomorphism", given it has a standard meaning different from what I'm after. That said: I think isomorphism and anti-isomorphism [as you define them] of groups are equivalent only when the target group is abelian? (Also, presumably there is a more general category-theoretic idea, of a functor from $\mathcal{A}$ to $\mathcal{B}^\textbf{op}$?)

Comment: $f(x)$ is an anti-isomorphism iff $g(x)=f(x^{-1})$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: @MarkSapir: OK your point was: groups are isomorphic iff they are anti-isomorphic (with the witnessing functions differing as described). Gotcha. Thanks! Well this only further confirms that I must avoid the name "anti-isomorphism" for what I am defining, since being isomorphic is not the same as being anti-isomorphic [in the sense I defined it]!

Answer (score 4):

Tim has drawn my attention to this (Thank you, Tim!)  Perhaps i should provide what Old Lags do in this kind of setting, namely provide some ancient history.

The context is Quine's NF.  Let us say the *dual* of a formula of the language of set theory is the result of replacing all occurrences of $\in$ by `$\not\in$'. It's routine to show that the dual of any axiom of NF is a theorem of NF.  Thus if we take $<$M,$\in>$ a model of NF and consider M equipped with the complement (in MxM) of the membership relation we get another model of NF!  Are these two structures elementarily equivalent?  Not reliably!  Might they be isomorphic?  If they are, then the isomorphism is an **antimorphism**.  Of course - since this is NF - there is the possibility that (not only might there be an antimorphism but) the antimorphism is a set of the model!  It's unknown if this can happen.  The best i can do is show that every model of NF is elementarily equivalent (with respect to stratifiable formul{\ae}) to one with two (set) permutations $\sigma$ and $\tau$ satisfying
both
$$(\forall x y)(x \in y \leftrightarrow \sigma(x) \not\in \tau(y))$$ 
and
$$(\forall x y)(x \in y \leftrightarrow \tau(x) \not\in \sigma(y))$$

Arranging for $\sigma = \tau$ is beyond me at the moment. The word
`antimorphism' is a coinage of your humble correspondent, tho' i can't give you chapter and verse.

Sorry if some readers find this perhaps off-piste, but this is the context of Tim's question, and might be helpful.

Thomas Forster www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~tf

Answer (score 2):

In the case of an anti-isomorphism we could identify $B$ with $A$ in which case $f$ is the identity function but each predicate for $B$ is the negation of that predicate in $A.$  This is essentially what you did in a comment with $(A \times A) \setminus\mathord{\in^\mathcal{A}}.$

For the unary case of each predicate indicating belonging or not belonging to a certain subset,  one gets the set complements.  If the model was a simple graph with loops allowed then we have the complementary graph. There the set is the vertices. If one wished to avoid loops then the set could be the pairs of vertices though that reduces to the previous example. Similarly a linear order and the reverse order. Again the pairs $(a,a)$ need care so either take the set to be ordered pairs of distinct elements or else semi-strong linear orders meaning no assumption of reflexive or non-reflexive.

What does Church-Oswald set theory does with the possibility that $a \in a?$ I suppose that again it could be permitted on an element by element basis.

Comment: Graph theory is one place I'd expect to encounter these maps, for exactly the reasons you say: the construction which deletes all the edges on a graph, then adds new edges (allowing for loops) where there are none before, gives you an anti-isomorphic [in my terminology] graph. This works for directed graphs too. Then set theory can be considered as a theory of directed graphs. Most set theories shun the possibility of self-membered sets, but Church-Oswald deliberately allows for them. (So $a \in a$ is totally unproblematic, and one can have an anti-automorphism [in my terminology].)